# Base converting in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, converters

My assignment (needed to be done in Python 3.3) is as follows:

Write a function named 'to_decimal()' that gets as input a string s and a number b (in range(2, 37)) and returns the positive number (type float) who's representation in base b is s. You may not use the functions float() or int().

Examples given:

```
>>> to_decimal('123.45', 10) -> 123.45
>>> to_decimal('3e8.6', 16) -> 1000.375
>>> to_decimal('10q', 30) -> 926
```

I wrote the following implantation:

```
def to_decimal(s,b):
  allowed = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.'
  result = [0, 0]
  number = s.split('.')
  assert len(number) < 3 and len(number) > 0
  for i in range(len(number)):
      for letter in number[i]:
          assert letter in allowed[:b]
          result[i] = result[i] * b + allowed[:b].index(letter)
  if result[1] == 0:
      return result[0]
  else:
      intger = result[0]
      fraction = result[1]
      while fraction > 1:
          fraction /= 10
      return intger + fraction
```

It's good for the first one and for the last one, but for the second example it's output is '1000.6'. I checked with WolframAlpha, and it should be as it is in the example.

Can you please help me figure out what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dividing fractional part by power of 10, but you should divide by power of `b`.

Also, your iterative guessing of power needed to divide fractional part is wrong. Consider `to_decimal('0.0001', 10)`, your code will return `0.1`. All you need is:

```
fraction /= b ** len(number[1])
```